# Import empty string value to MySQL as date

Tags: python, mysql, string

I have a string array that I am importing to a MySQL table, containing strings but also date strings (e.g. '2017-01-01'). Some dates are zero ('') and MySQL does not recognise these as dates. Since I am using a string array I cannot use NULL.

How can I pass a zero date value to my table by using a string value? The result in the table should be null, not '00-00-0000' for example.

Thanks!

Comment: I really dont understand where is problem. Both Mysql types DATE and DATETIME can be null so simple if date is "" then insert null into Mysql?

Comment: Sorry let me be more specific. I am creating a csv file from a string array, and then importing that CSV into MySQL. If the date is '' in the csv file, MySQL does not recognise this as a date and gives an error.

Comment: I mean exactly what i have said. Check my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add simple condition for check value of date

```
date = some_date_from_cvs

if date is not "":
    mysql.insert(date)
else:
    mysql.insert(NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, you have to check if the string is empty then simple get the current Date using python script.

```
import time
## dd/mm/yyyy format
cur_date = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
if str is in ['', None]:
    str = cur_date
```

After getting the date simply import to MYSQL.